# Proper term for conjoined choice buttons

Tags: buttons, terminology, radio-buttons, component

I'm thinking of using a set of "conjoined choice buttons" to let the user filter a table of highscores. It would look sort of like this:

```
  _______________________________
( ##EVERYONE##|  FRIENDS  |  ME   )     ---- everyone selected
  ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
  _______________________________
(   EVERYONE  |##FRIENDS##|  ME   )     ---- friends selected
  ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

Is there a proper name for this kind of component?

---

Names I tried Googling but didn't get results for:

- Linked choice buttons
- Sticking together choice buttons
- Conjoined (choice) buttons
- Merged choice buttons

Hopefully the next person searching for them will find the answer here.

Comment: In the simplest manner, they're a type of radio button in the same way that tabs are a type of radio button.

Comment: @zzzzBov Yes, from a technical point of view, but not from a user expectation point of view.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is called a *Segment Control* on iOS

[image]

and *[Segmented Radio Buttons](https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton)* on other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

They referred to as "button groups" in bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html

In the Android ICS you would probably use tabs to switch views: http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

Comment: I'm not intending to use it for tab-like functionality.